# Nvidia Docker GPU UI stutter on 20.04

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, docker

I was running ubuntu 20.04 with Nvidia 460.53 fine. For some GPU CUDA coding I was using Nvidia-Docker2 images and that was fine too.

I recently upgrade the cpu to a 5950x and upgraded from 5.4 to 5.11 kernel. Now whenever I run a nvidia-docker2 container the ui can hang for up to a minute. If I run jupyter in a nvidia container than every few minutes itll hang for a minute too. (I am guessing it is doing some sort of gpu render refresh)

Also same with any gpu commands in the docker container. ie if I run `import cudf` an nvidia library which uses gpu in a python commandline my ui will hang for a minute or so.

I have tried purging nvidia drivers and nvidia docker2 and reinstalling but this happens. I checked and reenabled SVT and IOMMU in Bios for virtualisation but no effect either.

Any ideas what to check next?

---

update:

Okay I reverted to `Linux 5.4.0-72-generic`
and did a purge and reinstall of `460.73.01` driver from Nvidia official website along with `nvidia-docker2`

Still getting stutters. I have been watching the logs in:
`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`
`/var/log/Xorg.1.log`
and can't see any errors from that.

I did notice that lag spikes come with 100% GPU usage and 100% usage on one cpu core (as seen in htop)
The process maxing out will be
`/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -norest -keeptty -verbose 3`

Comment: The 5.11 kernel is a *testing grade* kernel for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and not due for production use until 20.4.3 which currently is scheduled for August 19, 2021 (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule but installed systems will get it before this date, the date refers to ISO release). Currently supported kernels are 5.4 (GA) or 5.8 (HWE) so why not use a supported (*production grade*) kernel?

Comment: I recall reading that I needed later kernel for the latest ryzen processors